# Objective C : Video Compositions

Tags: objective-c, video, composition

I need a bit of advice. I currently have 4 videos, 20 seconds in length each, and one MP3, 5 minutes in length.

I am merging these lot into one video, cycling every 3 seconds to the next video, for the duration of the MP3 track.

Problem 1: The videos are 20 seconds each, the MP3 is 5 minutes. It means that I will run out of video. I resolved this by running each the videos in a loop using AVMutableComposition, then exporting each of them to their new respective files.

Next, I have a fifth video in which the 4 videos plays simultaneously, each in their own quadrant of the video. This video is also compose in an AVMutableComposition which is then exported the a separate video file.

Lastly, I take these 5 videos and MP3 track, and create a composition, using AVMutableComposition again, cycling through the different videos every 3 seconds. Then I export them to the final video.

Now, the issue I'm sitting with is that exporting all those videos takes up a lot of time. Is there a way for me to use the created AVMutableComposition objects to create the final video, instead of exporting the videos and then adding them to the final composition?

Regards,
EZFrag